# How can I present the option to create a new related model instance alongside existing options presented in a Django form from a ManyToMany field?

Tags: python, django

I am building an auction website a la eBay, and want to, when adding a new listing, be able to associate 0 or more categories with that listing. Specifically I would like a Categories CheckboxSelectMultiple (or similar?) that:

- Lists all existing categories as options
- **Presents an option to create a new category** which, when selected, presents a CharField, the value of which will be saved as the title of a new category, and thenthat category and the new listing associated with each other. (Please disregard the matter of whether or not this is a good design choice – I actually decided to simply have a fixed set of available categories and not offer the option to create a new one, BUT I am still curious to know how to do this)

I have the following m2m relationship set up in models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Listing(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
    ...
```

and, on GET request, am passing the following ModelForm from forms.py to my new_listing.html template:

```
class ListingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        widgets = {'categories': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple}
        fields = ['title', 'categories','starting_price', 'image_url', 'description']
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to do this, any help is much appreciated!